# Doing something good 3 times is like a neder. Can the 3 times be even in the same day?

Tags: halacha, minhag, nedarim-shevuot

An acquaintance told me that the 3 times must occur on 3 separate days but I cannot find a source for this, please let me know if you know of a source either way.

Comment: Sounds like a Zavah

Comment: Or the machlokes by shor hamuad? @DoubleAA

Answer (score -1):

For the English translation, see this website: https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.67.7?lang=bi

מִי שֶׁנָּהַג אֵיזֹה חֻמְרָא בִּדְבָרִים הַמֻּתָּרִים מִדִּינָא, מֵחֲמַת סְיָג וּפְרִישׁוּת, כְּגוֹן תַּעֲנִיּוֹת שֶׁבִּימֵי הַסְּלִיחוֹת, אוֹ שֶׁלֹּא לֶאֱכֹוֹל בָּשָׂר וְשֶׁלֹּא לִשְׁתּוֹת יַיִן מִשִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּתַמּוּז וָאֵילַךְ, וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּזֶה, אֲפִלּוּ לֹא נָהַג כֵּן רַק פַּעַם הָרִאשׁוֹנָה, אֶלָא שֶׁהָיָה בְּדַעְתּוֹ לִנְהוֹג כֵּן לְעוֹלָם, **אוֹ שֶׁנָּהַג כֵּן שָׁלֹשׁ פְּעָמִים**, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁלֹּא הָיָה בְּדַעְתּוֹ לִנְהוֹג כֵּן לְעוֹלָם, וְלֹא הִתְנָה שֶׁיְהֵא בְּלִי נֵדֶר, וְרוֹצֶה לַחֲזוֹר מִפְּנֵי שֶׁאֵינוֹ בָרִיא, צָרִיךְ הַתָּרָה, וְיִפְתַּח בַּחֲרָטָה, שֶׁהוּא מִתְחָרֵט עַל מַה שֶּׁנָּהַג כֵּן לְשֵׁם נֶדֶר. לָכֵן מִי שֶׁהוּא רוֹצֶה לִנְהוֹג בְּאֵיזֶה חֻמְרוֹת לִסְיָג וּפְרִישׁוּת, יֹאמַר בָּתְחִלָּה שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְקַבֵּל עָלָיו כֵּן בְּנֶדֶר, וְגַם יֹאמַר שֶׁאֵין בְּדַעְתּוֹ לִנְהוֹג כֵּן אֶלָּא בַּפַּעַם הַהִיא, אוֹ בִּפְּעָמִים שֶׁיִּרְצֶה וְלֹא לְעוֹלָם (רי"ד).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be better if you translated the passage you provided.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question?